# Accessing context value within a hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to use the Context API, but I am facing a problem to use the value within a React hook.

This is how I create my Context:

```js
import React from 'react'

export const DecimalSeparatorContext = React.createContext('.')

export function getDecimalSeparator () {
  return React.useContext(DecimalSeparatorContext) || '.'
}

export function isDecimal (value: string): boolean {
  const decimal = getDecimalSeparator()
  return !!value && value.includes(decimal)
}
```

This is how I insert it into my application:

```js
const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ decimalSeparator = '.' }) => {
  return (
    <DecimalSeparatorContext.Provider value={decimalSeparator}>
    ...
    </DecimalSeparatorContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

But when I want to use it within a hook, I get an error:

```js
   const Component = (props) => {
     useEffect(() => isDecimal(myDecimal),[myDecimal])
     // -> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
   }
```

I understand that I cannot execute useContext within a hook.

So what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run useContext right before the useEffect?

Something like that:

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const myDecimal = isDecimal('12.3');
    useEffect(() => {
      if(myDecimal) {
        // use myDecimal here
      }
    },[])
}
```

Comment: This will work, indeed. The issue is that I need to use the data within the useEffect. Let me edit the example to show this better